# Run PHP script after another?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have 2 PHP action scripts (action_myquiz) and (action_sendemailquiz), the first script is linked to a form that captures data from the user and stores it in a table in my database.

My second script selects the last inputted record from the table above and sends it to an external email marketing group.

Question is how can i run the second script straight after the first one has executed? Currently i am just pasting the URL of the second one and running it manually for testing purposes but now i need to automate it. Does this need a cron job or is there another way of doing this?

**Script 1**

```
public function action_myquiz() {
    $this->template->styles['assets/css/myquiz.css'] = 'screen';
    $this->template->jscripts[] = 'assets/scripts/myquiz.js';
    $this->template->content = View::factory('quiz/myquiz');
        $this->template->content->thanks = false;
        if ($this->request->post('entry')) {
            $post = $this->request->post('entry');

            // save participant's info
            $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `myquiz` (`support_you`, `mattress_collections`, `what_game`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `confirm_email`, `phone`, `postcode`)
                                                                        VALUES (:support_you, :mattress_collections, :what_game, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :confirm_email, :phone, :postcode)');                                                     

            $stmt->param(':support_you', $post['support_you']);
            $stmt->param(':mattress_collections', $post['mattress_collections']);
            $stmt->param(':what_game', $post['what_game']);
            $stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
            $stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
            $stmt->param(':email', $post['email']);
            $stmt->param(':confirm_email', $post['confirm_email']);
            $stmt->param(':phone', $post['phone']);
            $stmt->param(':postcode', $post['postcode']);
            try {
                $stmt->execute();
            //  var_dump($post);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                FB::error($e);
            }

            $this->template->content->thanks = true;
        }
    }
```

**Script 2**

```
public function action_sendemailquiz(){

    $results = DB::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'postcode')->from('myquiz')->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->execute();
    $users = $results->as_array();
     foreach($users as $user)
    {
     echo 'First Name: '.$user['first_name'];
     echo 'Last Name: '.$user['last_name'];
     echo 'Email: '.$user['email'];
     echo 'Postcode: '.$user['postcode'];
    }
            .................rest of my code
```

Comment: it should be as simple as `action_myquiz(); action_sendemailquiz();` but i think you need to give more info on the context

Comment: if they're in classes like it seems so then instantiate those classes within a separate script and call the methods in sequence like andrew suggested; but if you want to automate it use a cron